# How to get all full path list by a folder name?

Tags: directory

I want to get all the full path by a folder name called autoload, in my config i had split it like this file structure.

```
├── init.el
├── packs
│   ├── +completion
│   │   ├── ivy
│   │   │   ├── autoload
│   │   │   │   ├── evil.el
│   │   │   │   ├── hydras.el
│   │   │   │   └── ivy.el
│   │   │   └── config.el
│   ├── +editor
│   │   ├── fold
│   │   │   ├── autoload
│   │   │   │   ├── fold.el
│   │   │   │   └── hideshow.el
```

so i want get all autoload folders path list, this function will return a list like 
`("/User/xxxx/.emacs.d/packs/+completion/ivy/autoload/","/User/xxxx/.emacs.d/packs/+editor/fold/autoload/")`. thanks!

Comment: So you want all directories under a given directory that are at a given depth? Something like what `find /User/xxxx/.emacs.d -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d` would do?

Comment: just to given a folder like `eva-packs-dir` . i had define `eva-packs-dir`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Does the `find` command above give you what you want (I know it's not emacs, but I'm just trying to understand your requirements)? Perhaps @rpluim's answer below does what you want?

Answer (score 2):

```
(cl-remove-if-not #'file-directory-p (directory-files-recursively "name-of-directory" "autoload" t))
```

`directory-files-recursively` seems not well-known for some
reason. See
[Directories](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Contents-of-Directories.html)
for a fuller explanation.

Comment: That will find subdirectories at every level, correct? Maybe that's what the OP wants, maybe not: the question is not clear on that point.

Comment: Every level, yes. Salt with `(length (split-string file "/" t))` to check the depth.